# How to implement paginations in function base views in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-pagination

i know how to implement pagination in class base views using `ListView`

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
       model = product
       template_name = 'products/product_list.html'  
       context_object_name = 'products'
       ordering = ['-pub_date']
       paginate_by = 5
```

but i don't know how to implement paginations in function base views. i read that we have to import Paginator for `django.core.paginator` and use it in functions base view like this `paginator = Paginator(qs, 5)` but it's not working.

```
    def Productlistview(request):
       qs = product.objects.all()
       location_search = request.GET.get('location')
       print(location_search)
       categories = request.GET.get('categories')
       price = request.GET.get('price')
       ordering = ['-pub_date']
       paginator = Paginator(qs, 5)
       if location_search != "" and location_search is not None:
              qs = qs.filter(location__contains=location_search)

     context = {
       'posts': qs
      }

    return render(request, "products/product_list.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [*Pagination* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/). You indeed use a paginator, but you still need to pass the page that you want to show. This is often done through a GET parameter, like for example `page`. Furthermore you should do the filtering and ordering *before* paginating.

```
def product_list_view(request):
    qs = product.objects.all()
    location_search = request.GET.get('location')
    print(location_search)
    categories = request.GET.get('categories')
    price = request.GET.get('price')
    if location_search:
        qs = qs.filter(location__contains=location_search)
    qs = qs.order_by('-pub_date')
    paginator = Paginator(qs, 5)
    page = p.page(request.GET.get('page'))
     context = {
       'posts': page
      }

    return render(request, "products/product_list.html", context)
```